# Representación gráfica en Python de datos en formato JSON provenientes del puerto serial (Arduino)

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino, pyserial

En python debo generar la representación gráfica de valores, provenientes del puerto serial en formato JSON, en tiempo real.

Ya logré la graficación de 2 valores pero tengo un problema con la escala creada.

Esta es la cadena de datos enviada por mi arduino:

```
{"LightSensor":754.00,"IR":28.00,"Visible":10.00,"UV":0.01,"CurrentSensor":-0.07,"VoltageDivider":1.2}
```

Este es el código en python que estoy utilizando:

```
from socket import timeout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import serial
import json 
from itertools import count
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#initialize serial port
arduinoData = serial.Serial('COM11', 9600, timeout = 10)

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()

x_values = []
y_values = []
z_values = []

index = count()

def animate(i):
    data = arduinoData.readline().decode("utf-8")
    dict_json = json.loads(data) 

    color1 = 'tab:blue'
    color2 = 'tab:red'

    x_values.append(next(index))
    y_values.append(dict_json.get("VoltageDivider"))
    z_values.append(dict_json.get("LightSensor"))

    ax1.plot(x_values, y_values, color1)
    ax1.set_ylabel("Tension")

    plt.cla()

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x_values, z_values, color2)
    ax2.set_ylabel("Luminosité")

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, 1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Y esto es lo que genera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La escala generada del lado izquierdo de las y, es correcta y concuerda con los valores recibidos en VoltageDivider. Sin embargo, del lado derecho se generan dos escalas, la correcta es la que va de 0-700. No logro comprender por qué se crea la que va de 0-1.0

Apreciaría su ayuda...

Comment: Tu problema no es Arduino ni la serial, sino Matplotlib. Tienes que publicar el código Matplotlib que has intentado para tener un punto de partida para darte una respuesta.

Comment: Eliminá (o mejorá) el primer párrafo de tu pregunta. Solicitar recursos externos es un motivo de [cierre](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Hola! He editado mi pregunta debido a que avancé un poco desde la última vez y corregí el primer párrafo.